# How to use js to calculate input form fields in a sectioned form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form with 3 sections each of them triggered by a radio button. , i use js to calculate value of two of the input fields in each section, somehow just the first section works. the values i multiply with are gotten from php value of

below is my html code for the form

```
                                                    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                                                        <img src="../app-assets/images/pages/eth.png" height="30" alt="ETH Logo">
                                                        <input type="radio" name="option" onchange="hideB(this)" id="eth" value="ETH">
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                        
                                                    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                                                        <img src="../app-assets/images/pages/usdt.png" height="30" alt="USDT Logo">
                                                        <input type="radio" name="option" onchange="hideC(this)" id="usdt" value="USDT">
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <hr>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- BTC Row -->
                                        <div class="row" id="A">
                                           
                                                    <label for="value_n">Enter Your amount in USD </label>
                                                    <input type="text" id="value_btc" name="value_btc" class="form-control" onkeyup="mult(this.value)" placeholder="Enter Number of Your Value">
                                               
                                            </div>
                                         
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="lastName12">Amount in BTC</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="btc_rate" name="btc_rate" readonly="readonly" placeholder="Amount in BTC" >
                                                </div>
                                         
                                           
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="lastName12">Amount You will Receive (BTC - ₦ NAIRA)</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="receive_btc" name="receive_btc" readonly="readonly" placeholder="Amount in Naira" >
                                                </div>
                                        

                                           
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control copy-to-clipboard" id="copy-to-clipboard-input" value="BTC WALLET GOES HERE" readonly>
                                                    </div>
                                           

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- ETH Row -->
                                        <div class="row" id="B" style="display:none">
                                          
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="firstName13">Enter Your amount in USD </label>
                                                    <input type="text" id="value_eth" name="value_eth" class="form-control" onkeyup="mult2(this.value)" placeholder="Enter Number of Your Value">
                                        
                                            </div>
                                          
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="lastName12">Amount in ETH</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eth_rate" name="eth_rate" readonly="readonly" placeholder="Amount in ETH" >
                                             
                                            </div>
                                           
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="lastName12">Amount You will Receive (ETH - ₦ NAIRA)</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="receive_eth" name="receive_eth" readonly="readonly" placeholder="Amount in ETH" >
                                                </div>
                                            



                                        <!-- USDT Row -->
                                        <div class="row" id="C" style="display:none">
                                            
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="value_usdt">Enter Your amount in USD </label>
                                                    <input type="text" id="value_usdt" name="value_usdt" onkeyup="mult3(this.value)" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Number of Your Value">
                                             
                                            </div>
                                          
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="usdt_rate">Amount in USDT</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usdt_rate" name="usdt_rate" name="usdt_rate" readonly="readonly" placeholder="Amount in USDT" >
                                            
                                            </div>
                                        
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="receive_usdt">Amount You will Receive (USDT - ₦ NAIRA)</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="receive_usdt" name="receive_usdt" readonly="readonly" placeholder="Amount in USDT" >
                                         
                                            </div>




                                       
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-1 mb-1">Submit</button>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

and below my js for calculating and autopopulating

```
       <script>
    
            function mult(value_btc) {
                var btc_rate = "<?php echo $btc_rate; ?>";
                var naira_rate = "<?php echo $naira_rate; ?>";
                 var x, y ;
                x = value_btc / btc_rate ;
                y = value_btc * naira_rate;
    
                document.getElementById('btc_rate').value = x;
                document.getElementById('receive_btc').value = y;
            };
    
        </script>
    
        <script>
    
            function mult2(value_eth) {
                
               
             var x, y ;
                x = 23 / 5 ;
                y = 10 * 10;
    
                document.getElementById('eth_rate').value = w;
                document.getElementById('receive_eth').value = z;
            };
    
        </script>
    
    
    <script>
    
    function mult3(value_usdt) {
    
     var x, y ;
        x = 4 / 5 ;
        y = 456 * 7 ;
    
        document.getElementById('usdt_rate').innerHtml = x;
        document.getElementById('receive_usdt').innerHtml = x;
    };
    
    </script>


javascript for hiding and revealing  form

<script>
    function hideA(x) {
    if (x.checked) {
        document.getElementById("A").style.display = "flex";
        document.getElementById("B").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("C").style.display = "none";
    }
    }

    function hideB(x) {
    if (x.checked) {
        document.getElementById("A").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("B").style.display = "flex";
        document.getElementById("C").style.display = "none";
    }
    }
    function hideC(x) {
    if (x.checked) {
        document.getElementById("A").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("B").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("C").style.display = "flex";
    }
    }
</script>
```

i will appreciate any help or direction

Comment: Please produce a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) So that we can help you quickly with ease. In your case please add the HTML of only three sections without any deep nesting. (Like only the required HTML input fields). Provide a sample value for the PHP variable

Comment: ive minimized it as much as possible....think of php variables as any positive numbers

Comment: Ok. I meant is it possible to minimize the HTML code you have given. It would be easy to work with. There are about 200 lines of HTML code here. Can you add only the required input elements

Comment: Made it better.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly are you trying to achieve? I tried running your code. It works fine here. the amount I enter in usd is converted to BTC and amount recieved.

Comment: i want the same for ETH and USDT

Comment: Ok. I can see there is a radio button with ETH and USDT. They have the functions `hideB` and `hideC`. Can you please add those functions as well?

Comment: i added  the code for the radio buttons

Comment: Thank you. I went through your code thoroughly and it seems a little hard to understand what's really happening since the naming conventions are not properly followed. I will give a detailed explanation in my answer. To solve the problem I need few more information. It seems like you are making a calculator. You want to convert USD to ETH, BTC, USDT. Am I correct? Now, please include the exact formula that you use in both of these three conversions in your question please

Comment: Correct, SO im calling defined rates of BTC ETH AND USDT from Database using my sql and php. converting the values into js with php echo, for BTC, ETH and USDT i divide the user input by the rate to get Coin value, and the third read only input i multiply by a rate also gotten from data base. You can use any numbers my .problem is when i switch the form, the js doesnt activate. but it works on BTC which is the first active form

Comment: Ok brother, I could understand. To give you a proper solution I am looking for the formulas you use to calculate in BTC, ETH and USDT. I hope you understand what I am trying to convey. Can you include them in your answer please?

Comment: for BTC its (USER INPUT/ CURRENT BTC PRICE) same for ETH and USDT

Comment: Well understood and I'll work on your solution

Comment: Firstly: your code is really messed up, you must clean it up. Secondly: In your mult2 and mult3 function,s you don't even use the parameter passed to the function. So you might want to correct it. Thirdly: usdt_rate input, has name attribute two times. So get rid of one of it.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because your code contains several errors:

### mult2

---

```
function mult2(value_eth) {


  var x, y;
  x = 23 / 5;
  y = 10 * 10;

  document.getElementById('eth_rate').value = w;
  document.getElementById('receive_eth').value = z;
};
```

- `value_eth` is never used.
- `document.getElementById('eth_rate').value = w;` -> where `w` has been declared? -> error
- `document.getElementById('receive_eth').value = z;` -> where `z` has been declared? -> error

### mult3

---

```
function mult3(value_usdt) {

  var x, y;
  x = 4 / 5;
  y = 456 * 7;

  document.getElementById('usdt_rate').innerHtml = x;
  document.getElementById('receive_usdt').innerHtml = x;
};
```

- `value_usdt` is never used.
- `document.getElementById('usdt_rate').innerHtml = x;` -> It is an input, so you cannot update the innerHtml.
- `document.getElementById('receive_usdt').innerHtml = x;` -> It is an input, so you cannot update the innerHtml.

---

I've made a JSFiddle which might be close from your use cases.

https://jsfiddle.net/n0uLbxef/70/

Also, some tips:

You don't need to modify the html to hide or display something. I guess you're using bootstrap. Just add the `visually-hidden` class if the input is selected on the section you need to hide.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your values are stored in the variable, use the DOM `innerHTML` property.

```
document.getElementById('usdt_rate').innerHtml = x;
```

For more information refer this [w3school-link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

Comment: Thanks Deshan, i tried that but same results

Comment: document.getElementById('usdt_rate').textContent = string   (try it converting to a string and assign)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent